# What's the meaning of the shoelace scene in Homecoming?

Tags: plot-explanation, homecoming

In the episode 4 season 1 of Homecoming there's a scene where Thomas asks Colin a few questions about the Homecoming project and Heidi. Thomas tells he found a client and will talk to him, and enters the elevator. Right after the door closes, Colin seems upset and just gazes at his shoes, and the shoelaces are undone.

Is there a metaphor here? What does this scene mean? Do the undone shoelaces represent something?

Answer (score 3):

### *"Is there a metaphor here? What does this scene mean? Do the undone shoelaces represent something?"*

Yes, I believe you are right! Sometimes shots like this are creating a metaphor by showing the metaphor "literally" in the shot, which then adds some additional irony. Sometimes this is called [literal metaphor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiteralMetaphor), but I think in this case it is closer to a [visual pun](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VisualPun)...

The scene is about having "loose ends" and things not being tied up properly. The Client is Colin's potential loose end that could expose him, Mirror Pond's Homecoming Program, and Geist.

Comment: Also they did something in the same scenes that was also interesting, because Colin is trying to shake him down with questions about 'proof of truth' and right when Thomas answers "no" to one, Colin hits the "down" button on the elevator and many would probably associate no with down (or up with yes) and that too plays into Colin's whole debate about real correlations vs creating fake ones! Really dizzyingly brilliant writing/acting/directing there!

Comment: Yes, indeed! I also thought about the loose ends metaphor, but since it looked quite obvious I wondered if there was another meaning to it.

Comment: You never know! Maybe somebody else will find more meaning! The only other thing that came to mind, but this is probably a stretch, is thinking about how untied shoe laces could lead one to "trip" (aka get tripped-up), which is not unlike a potential result of a loose end, but the word "trip" has more significance when one think about Homecoming's use of thematic "road trips".